# In Java, why do certain variables need initialization at first and others only need declaration?

Tags: java, variables, initialization, declaration

I'm trying to understand on a deeper level if I'm missing something as to understanding when Java needs an initialization of a variable vs a simply declaration. In the following code, the variable 'row' doesn't need to be assigned a value to compile and run, however, the variable 'column' does.

Note: This program does nothing of use - it's been trimmed to display only whats necessary for this question as to not waste peoples valuable time.

Here's the code snippet:

```
int row;      //row doesn't need initialization
int column=0; //column does need initialization
for (row=0; row<2; row++){
    for (column=0; column<2; column++){
    }
}
System.out.print("Col:" + column + " row:" + row);
```

Why does `row` compile w/o initialization at the top, but Java thinks `column` "might not have been initialized."?

Comment: As Crozin mentions below, both vars need initialization. You just happen to be initializing row at line 3, but potentially never (according to the compiler) initializing column if you don't do it at line 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `row = 0` (from outer loop) is guaranteed to be evaluated, therefore `row` variable will always be initialized before being used. The `column` variable would be initialized if, and only if, outer loop would iterate at least once. In other words the expresion `column = 0` (from inner loop) is **not** guaranteed to be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Before both The `row` and `column` variables are used in the `System.out.println`, they need to be initialized,.  `row` is initialized in the outer loop so it is fine, but column is initialized in the inner loop and the compiler makes no assumption that this will ever run (even though it will in practice).

Answer (score 2):

The Java compiler can't follow your code. It sees that `column` gets initialized inside the body of the outer `for` loop, but has no way of being sure that that code will ever run. So it can't be sure that your variable will always be initialized before it's accessed in the call to `print`.

On the other hand, it knows that the initialization statement of the outer `for` loop is guaranteed to run no matter what. So it can guarantee that `row` will be initialized.

Comment: This seems backwards. The compiler *can* follow your code, and it can see that under certain conditions `column` will not be initialized.

Comment: In this particular example, `column` will always be initialized. What I was trying to say is that the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: I understand what you mean now.